# Small library for generating HTML files in C++

Tags: c++, html

Is there a library that will allow easier generation of a simple website using C++ code. This 'website' will then be compiled into a CHM help file (which is the final goal here). Ideally, it will allow generation of pages easily and allow links to be generated between pages easily. I can do this all by hand, but that is going be very tedious and error prone.

I know about bigger libraries such as Wt, but am more interested in smaller ones with little or no dependencies and a need for installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CTPP](http://ctpp.havoc.ru/en/) template engine. It is written in C++ is small and quite fast.

Do you need this project to be written in c++? Because if you just need to prepare documentation in CHM I would go with [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/). Sphinx is a set of tools written in Python that generate manuals in few formats (chm, html, LaTeX, PDF) from text files (formated using [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html) markup language). Those text files could be created by hand or using some application and then combined into one manual using Sphinx. In my work right now we are using this solution to write documentation, because it is very easy to maintain text files (merging, tracking changes etc.) than for example html or doc. Sphinx is used to generate Python language [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/) ([chm](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2/python32.chm)), so it is capable to handle really large project.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the **[FLATE library](http://flate.dead-inside.org/)** every day for ten years and it works flawlessly. It's a piece of cake to use; I can't recommend it enough.

It will definitely do the trick, though probably at a much lower level than you have in mind. It is a C-language source library that you can link with a C++ caller. It's also available as a Perl module, but I haven't used that.

---

#### [FLATE library](http://flate.dead-inside.org/)

**Flate is a template library used to deal with html code in CGI applications. The library includes C and Perl support. All html code is put in an external file (the template) and printed using the library functions: variables, zones (parts to be displayed or not) and tables (parts to be displayed 0 to n times). Using this method you don't need to modify/recompile your application when modifying html code, printing order doesn't matter in your CGI code, and your CGI code is much cleaner.**

---

HTH and good luck!

Comment: Seems dead, link is gone and Google can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Are [this CHM lib](http://www.jedrea.com/chmlib/) and the related links what you're looking for?